# Подключения модуля для работоспосбности функций Substring и Equals

Tags: delphi, строки, delphi-xe3

Какие модули надо подключить, чтобы работали функции `Substring` и `Equals` (работа со `string`) в `Delphi XE3`?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь [xploring Delphi XE3 – Record Helpers for simple types – System.SysUtils.TStringHelper](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/exploring-delphi-xe3-record-helpers-for-simple-types-system-sysutils-tstringhelper/)
Попробовать не могу, нет под рукой XE3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Delphi для получения подстроки используйте Copy:

```
function Copy(S: string; Index: Integer; Count: Integer): string;
```

А для сравнения обычно хватает оператора `=`. Ну или `SameText` из `SysUtils`.